# how to change the hyperlinks of WP Static HTML output

Tags: html, hyperlink, static, live

I have downloaded WP Static HTML output from my localhost site. I want to place the entire downloaded site on my live website. I uploaded all the contents of the WP Static HTML out folder to my live sit but only index.html is working. when i tried to open other pages that goes back to localhost address.
Please help me how to change the hyperlinks of localhost and how to easily run this live.
Thanks

Comment: Consider postion what the hyperlinks are currently so people can help you answering the question

Comment: The current hyperlinks are like localhost:8888/test and I have downloaded entire site using WP Static HTML Output tool. Now I want to run this localhost site on my live site.

Comment: If I'm correct you can enter a base URL when creating the export with WP Static HTML. Make sure you enter your domainname / Live http url in there instead of localhost:8888

Comment: Thanks a lot, lenders

Answer (score 1):

With in WP Static HTML Output you can set base URL. Change this to the domain of where your export wil be uploaded. This way all your links will start with the propper URL.